# How add class to a div after class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a child div that needs to be added with a class using jQuery.

```
<div class="main-content">
     <article class="post status-publish">
          <div class="post-content>
               <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">

                    <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
                    </div>   

                </div>
          </div>
     </article>
</div>
```

The jQuery code that i tried so far is this:

```
j('.main-content .post-content').each(function () {
    j(this).after().addClass('home-inner-content');
});
```

This is the result that i am desiring for:

```
<div class="main-content">
     <article class="post status-publish">
          <div class="post-content>
               <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid home-inner-content">

                    <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
                </div>   

            </div>
          </div>
     </article>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
j('.main-content .post-content').each(function () {
    j(this).children().first().addClass('home-inner-content');
});
```

[`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) is for inserting content, not locating it.

But really, I don't think you need a loop. You can do:

```
j('.main-content .post-content > *:first-child').addClass('home-inner-content');
```

The first part selects the elements you want. [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) adds a class to each of the elements that got selected.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sure it is. OP has clearly implied that they have jQuery's `$` mapped to `j`.

Comment: Well yeah, but why... it's not even standard to do that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If you mean, "Why would OP do that in their environment," sometimes there are extenuating circumstances. If you you mean, "Why would you use a non-standard convention when asking/answering a question?", I'm not sure about OP's reasons, but I believe it helps make the answer clearer to the asker if I don't quibble over details unrelated to answering the question and just try to answer in the context the asker provides. (Though OP should've asked using a context that would be clearer to would-be answerers.)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, next code will help.

```
$('.main-content .post-content>div').addClass('home-inner-content');
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.main-content .post-content').each(function() {
  $(this).children().addClass('home-inner-content');
});
```

```css
body * {
  padding-left: 1em; 
}

body *:before {
  font-family: monospace;
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
  <article class="post status-publish">
    <div class="post-content">
      <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">
        <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use each function here.

`j('.main-content .post-content>div').addClass('home-inner-content');`